# Website's folder permision changing autometically after some times

Tags: php, wordpress, server

Here is a wired issue with my website . I have a GoDaddy host running Apache and WordPress cms. The issue is that after some time my `wp-admin` and wp-`include's` directory permissions are changing automatically, and the websites stop working. I have set the permission `644` to folder,  but now it's `604`. If i reupload the `wp-admin` and `wp-include` folder, then it works. The same problem will occur after sometime. Can anybody tell me what the issue is?

Comment: My advice: stay as far as possible from `GoDaddy`. We struggled for two years with its buggy system until we decided to move to another host service and it was really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GoDaddy's backend (I use eNom), but if the WordPress install is managed by Parallels or some other hosting software, it could be that you have automatic background update enabled for WordPress and every time WP updates, it is changing the folder permissions.

You can [check this list of WP releases](https://wordpress.org/news/category/releases/) and compare the release dates to when your permissions are being botched.  If they match up, then this is probably the issue.

Comment: Agree with @enb081 that GoDaddy is notorious for problems on the hosting side, so def would behoove you to get off their system.  That being said, have you checked any log files to try and track down the issue?  Are you running any plugins that could be messing things up? You could also set up a cron job that runs every hour or so that notifies you when permissions have changed from their proper state and this might help you track down the problem.